# How can I use callback when output was printed to stdout in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, spawn

I am writing scripts for watching servers status.
I can write the code in javascript, but I have to write it in ruby.

In javascript,it can be done using node.js like this.

```js
var iostat = require('child_process').spawn("iostat", ["-w 1"]);
iostat.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This code executes iostat command and output to console every second.
How can I implement the same thing in ruby?
In other words, I want to use callback when stdout was printed in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to do this, but you can do things like this:

```
module PutsWatcher
  def puts(string)
    super("***#{string}***")
  end
end

$stdout.extend PutsWatcher

puts "here"
# => "***here***"
```

It's a little weird if you do this in IRB or Pry, because they produce output themselves, on top of your own (i.e. the `nil` after you do `puts`), but here's a copy/paste from pry:

```
pry(main)> module PutsWatcher
pry(main)*   def puts(string)
pry(main)*     super("***#{string}***")
pry(main)*   end
pry(main)* end
=> nil
pry(main)> $stdout.extend PutsWatcher
***=> #<IO:<STDOUT>>
***
pry(main)> puts "yo"
***yo***
***=> nil
***
pry(main)>
```

By the way, I'm not advising you do this... patching core classes is generally a bad idea.  I mention it purely for academic purposes.

Comment: Actually, I didn't intend such things.
For example,if I write the code like this,

`puts 'iostat -w 1'`

I never get the result because the iostat continue to output.
But, I want get the result every second, then process it every time continuously.